# Simple Probability with three variables and evidence

Tags: probability

Simple question. How does does the left part calculate to the right? I'm still learning this so I have no clue:

P(cavity, toothache, catch | E) = P(cavity, catch | toothache, E)P(toothache | E)

Comment: Based on the first two words, you have here a dental problem :) But what do you mean here by "catch" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $P(A \cap B) = P(A | B)P(B)$. Using the formula for conditional probability and in this case, letting $A = \text{cavity} \wedge \text{catch}$ and $B = \text{toothache}$, the above result should follow.

Comment: It does make sense! So basically P(A, B, C) = P(A, C, B)?

Comment: Yes, the commas is just another way of saying "and", of which, the "and" operator is commutative.